# neo4j cluster: No such log version

Tags: neo4j

I try use neo4j HA cluster (neo4j 2.0.1), but I got error "No such log version: ..." after database copied from master.

I deleted all *.log files, but it was not help for me.

Can you help me with this problem?

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

"Log" in Neo4j refers to the write-ahead-log that the database uses to ensure durability and consistency. It is stored in files named something like nioneo_logical_log.vX, where X is a number. You should *never* delete these files manually, even if the database is turned off, this may lead to data loss. If you wish to limit the amount of disk space used by neo for logs, use this configuration:

```
keep_logical_logs=128M
```

The error you are seeing means that the database copied cannot perform an incremental update to catch up with the master, because the log files have been deleted. This may happen normally, if the copy is very old, or if you have keep_logical_logs set to false.

What you need to do to resolve this is to set keep_logical_logs to some value that makes sense to you, perhaps "keep_logical_logs=2 days" to keep logs up to two days old around. Once you've done that, you need to do a new full store copy on your slave, which can be triggered by shutting the slave off, deleting the database folder (data/graph.db), and starting the slave back up again.

Newer versions of Neo will do this automatically.